# Angular refresh kills user session

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-cookies

I have a problem with my angular app- after a user signs in, if he hits the refresh button, the signin info is lost and the app redirects to the log in page. I found a SO answer for something similar  [here using $cookieStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408475/how-to-keep-login-status-after-refresh-using-angular-js) but I don't think it can work for me as I'm not using cookies. Can anyone suggest a solution? Here's my authorization service-

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.services');

app.factory('SignIn', ['$resource', '$q', function($resource, $q) {
    var signInUrl = 'https://example.com'
    var API = $resource(signInUrl, {}, {
        signIn: {
            withCredentials: true,
            url: signInUrl + '/session',
            method: 'POST'
        },
        signOut: {
            url: authApiUrl + '/session',
            method: 'DELETE'
        },
        currentUser: {
            url: signInUrl + '/users/@me',
            method: 'GET'
        }
    });


    var _currentUser = undefined;

    return {
        isAuthenticated: function() {
            return !!_currentUser;
        },
        getUser: function(){
            var d = $q.defer();

            // If _currentUser is undefined then we should get current user
            if (_currentUser === undefined) {
                API.currentUser(function(userData) {
                    _currentUser = userData;
                    d.resolve(userData);
                }, function(response) {
                    if (response.statusCode === 401) {
                        _currentUser = null;
                        d.resolve(_currentUser);
                    } else {
                        d.reject(response);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                d.resolve(_currentUser);
            }

            return d.promise;
        },
        signIn: function(username, password){
            var d = $q.defer();

            API.signIn({email: username, password: password}, function(data, headers){
                _currentUser = data;
                d.resolve(_currentUser);
            }, d.reject);

            return d.promise;
        },
        signOut: function(){
            var d = $q.defer();

            API.signOut(function(){
                _currentUser = null;
                d.resolve();
            }, d.reject);

            return d.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to keep track of the _currentUser data past a refresh then you could use sessionStorage within the browser. That extends all the way back to IE 8 and we really shouldn't be supporting any browsers before that anyway.

Usually these things are done with cookies though. When the client first makes a connection to the server (even before the first API call in some cases) a cookie is sent to the client so the server can maintain a session associated with that particular client. That's because the cookie is automatically sent back to the server with each request and the server can check its local session and say, "Oh, I'm talking to *this* user. Now I can use that additional piece of context to know if I can satisfy their API call or not."

You don't show any of your other API calls here but I'm guessing that you're sending something out of the _currentUser with each API call to identify the user instead? If so, that certainly works, and it avoids the need to synchronize cookies across multiple servers if you're clustering servers, but you're going to have to use something local like sessionStorage or localStorage that won't get dumped like your current in-memory copy of the data does when you refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer John, is sessionStorage something I would implement within my service?

Comment: Yes. I would check sessionStorage to see if the _currentUser data is already there before calling the server to get it. If it's not there, make the call and store it both into sessionStorage and your local variable. Dive Into HTML5 covers the use of localStorage and sessionStorage well (http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) but you might consider using a wrapper library to avoid having to deal with serializing/deserializing JSON, by default the storage APIs won't let you store anything but a string.

Comment: Hmm. I've just realised that the session isn't actually killed by the refresh, as it still does the api calls for data successfully. This may actually be some kind of routing issue.